# Grouping with DetachedCriteria without column selection

Tags: java, hibernate, projection, detachedcriteria

How to make grouping without selecting the column?

```
detachedCriteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("col1"));
```

OR

```
detachedCriteria.setProjection(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("col1", "col1", new String[]{}, new Type[] {Hibernate.INTEGER}));
```